# Balloon Overlay Not working Properly in Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am Using Balloon Overlay to show popup message on Tap it works fine With pinch to Zoom.
But i m having a problem that is when i zoom in map with Seek bar then the popup message does not appears on tap similarly If I zoom in map with with my custom defined radius then map Pin and circle is drawn perfeclty but pop Does not appears Screen shots are as following 
[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

now after zooming in map using seek bar Balloon overlap pop up is not shown on tap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time  Zoom in or zoom it requires to `clear();` map and then redraw overlay every time new overlay will be drawn and handle tap in `redrawmap()` method